# pass value from textbox in sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

so, i am trying to display the value of movie_id using movie name by getting the name from textblock(html). But the page displayed is blank and if i add a name manually in the query e.g name="skyfall" instead of the variable the result is displayed.

```
include './connection.php';

$movie_tf=$_POST['movie_tf'];

$getMovieIdQuery="SELECT movie_id FROM MOVIE WHERE name='$movie_tf'";
$query=  mysql_query($getMovieIdQuery);

if (!$query){
    echo 'error' .  mysql_error($dbconn);
}

    $getMovieIdQueryFetchRow=  mysql_fetch_row($query);
    echo $getMovieIdQueryFetchRow[0];


mysql_close($dbconn);
```

html form:

```
<form action="operations.php" method="GET">
            Movie:<input type="text" name="movie_tf"/> </br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: well *something* obviously failed, some *unknown* force

Comment: You should use `prepared statements` (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection. Anyway. What is displayed in your browser console (or log file) ?

Comment: just a sql depricated warning is displayed. But it does display the wanted result when i add a name of the movie manually instead of the variable. is my query syntax correct with the variable? @Seblor

Comment: If you're getting the deprecated notice you should learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Surely you have verified `$_POST['movie_tf']` content, right? The syntax is correct.

Comment: ^ the *unknown force*

Comment: *Tap, tap, tap....* - so, you going to show us the HTML form that should have gone with this?

Comment: added the form @Fred-ii-

Comment: @NelsonJohn added my answer ;-) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `method="GET"` for your form and then a POST array `$_POST['movie_tf']`

Either use `method="post"`

or `$_GET['movie_tf']` the choice is yours.

- Both the method and array type must match.

and strangely enough, you would not have gotten errors for it neither.

- I learned that lesson the hard way once.

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: bingo! #unknownForce

Comment: @NelsonJohn *hehe* yeah... that what the missing link ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @NelsonJohn *Cheers* :-)